# Swift Cannot convert Int to String with usual methods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

The general purpose of converting an Int into a String is to display a "Score", which is incremented by one, every time a SKSpriteNode is tapped. The gesture is recognized by my GameScene class in GameScene.swift. It then uses a struct named "variables" to send the "Score" to my GameViewController which will display the score via UILabel. This is were I need to convert the Int into a String. Simple. Except every method I've tried has ended with the error: **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**. Furthermore, whenever I try to treat "Score" as an optional (add a '?') XCode gives me another error and tells me to remove it.

**TL;DR**: I need to convert an Int into a String, and all the methods that usually work aren't.

Method's I've tried:

1. `scoreLabel.text = NSNumber(integer: Score).stringValue`
2. `scoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"`
3. `scoreLabel.text = String(Score)`
4. `scoreLabel.text = toString(Score)`
5. `scoreLabel.text = "\(Score.description)"`
6. `scoreLabel.text = Score.description`
7. `scoreLabel.text = "\(NSNumber(integer: Score).stringValue)"`

I've also restarted XCode and Mac. Have I missed something obvious? Please help a noob out.

EDIT #1: I forgot to mention that I've been logging "Score" in both GameScene.swift and GameViewController.swift; both return the correct value.

Comment: first question: why not use an sklabelnode instead of uilabel?

Comment: What you have tried should work, so clearly your problem is not in the Int to String conversion. Try printing the value of your `variables` struct after every statement once it is created or modified, and print it's value just before being used. This will help you see what is going on tremendously. If I had to guess, I would say that you just aren't initializing `variables` properly.

Comment: Also consider using NSNumberFormatter.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad "I don't know what I don't know", I'll go look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @Aderis If you mean logging it before I transfer it, and after it's been received, then I have.

Comment: @JamMySon lmao I see, no probs bro thats why we're here. Use sklabelnode for sprite kit, it was made for it :)

Comment: Since `Score` (and by the way it should be `score` - variable have a lower case letter, class names are capitals) isn't nil, the obvious question, what could be nil? The answer is `scoreLabel` - My guess is that this is nil because you haven't assigned the IBOutlet correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving isn't because of the proper code, its because your "Score" variable is nil. What I always use is ->

```
scoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"
```

Then, set your the value of your "Score" to 0 so its value can't be returned nil.

```
var Score : Int = 0
```

Finally, to display the score, you should use an SKLabelNode.

```
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "American Typewriter")
```

Then, in your `didMove(toView)`

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    scoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"
    scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.green
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 30
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height / 4)
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Abdul Ahmad suggested, I should use a SKLabelNode rather than a UILabel to display my score because I'm doing so from a subclass of SKScene. I don't know why the value couldn't be converted in my other class (as Aderis pointed out, all my methods should've worked), as I was able to log it using the same syntax and methods I was using to attempt to set the UILabel's text.

---

To any future googlers with the same problem:

1. Check your syntax
2. Log the value at every point it could change
3. Try to use similar classes? 
   (I used a SKScene to change the text of a SKLabelNode rather than a UILabel)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is swift checking type. You declare an optional value and when you use it. You need force it not nil.

```
// declare optional variable
var score: Int?

// Use it when you sure not nil
yourLabel.text = String(score!)
```

I advice you need to set initial value.

```
var score: Int = 0
```

And use it.

```
yourLabel.text = String(score)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Although I did init score four different ways per method (see question) including: var score: Int?, var score: Int!, var score: Int = 0, and var score = 0. Probably should've mentioned this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    let cast_this_optional_integer = Int(Score!)
    print(String(cast_this_optional_integer))
```